# Calculating the lower and upper bounds forVC-dimension of a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, decision-trees, data-science-model

I have a problem finding the lower and upper bounds of the decision tree. Suppose there is a decision tree with a hypothesis space of depth 2 and an input space with 10 variables (the variables take boolean values). How do I calculate the lower and upper bounds for the VC dimension of this tree? I was doing some reading and papers but couldn't actually establish a strong understanding of the technique. Even some answers on stack exchange were confusing. I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand this clearly.